# removing array brackets

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array, ruby-1.9.2

I think its' silly question lol

I have below array

```
[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
```

and want that array to be

```
['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']
```

which means i want to remove the first bracket.

Does that make sense?

Thanks in adv.

Comment: No this doesn't make sense, you want an array that consists of two arrays to be an array that consists of two arrays: the same thing? Why?

Comment: Because, i want to insert that into another array with out a loop. :)

Comment: i know exactly what you're asking, because I had the same question.  the short answer is "splat": `*[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]` here's my [post with the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916745/separate-an-array-of-arrays-to-be-passed-into-a-method-as-multiple-objects) :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, this doesn't make sense really, because ['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'] in this notation are **two separate objects/arrays not inside any other data structure**...

you could do an assignment, like :

```
a,b = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
```

and then

```
> a
 => ["a", "b", "c"] 
> b
 => ["d", "e", "f"]
```

or better just iterate over the outer array (because you don't know how many elements it has):

```
input = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
input.each do |x|
   puts "element #{x.inspect}"
end

=>
 element ["a", "b", "c"]
 element ["d", "e", "f"]
```

Comment: The whole idea is to insert those elements at once into another array. I don't want to use loop this time.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t make sense. Do you mean a string manipulation?

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]"
=> "[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]"
irb(main):002:0> s[1...-1]
=> "['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']"
```

Or, do you want to flatten an array?

```
irb(main):003:0> [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']].flatten
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```