# Separate an array of arrays to be passed into a method as multiple objects

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a method that accepts multiple arrays with a splat operator [taken from this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588752/1964078).

```
def interleave(a,*args)
    max_length = args.map(&:size).max
    padding = [nil]*[max_length-a.size, 0].max
    (a+padding).zip(*args).flatten.compact
end
```

I have an array of arrays:

```
my_array = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

how do i pass

```
interleave(my_array)
```

so that it passes the subarrays in separately?  I can't seem to separate `my_array` (of which there can be hundreds) into separate objects.

Comment: It sounds like you were asking how to pass in the subarrays in as separate method parameters (given your wording in the title and post), so I made a small edit to emphasize that.

Comment: personally, I would pass an array of arrays if they are of identical types. Having a splat for that makes your API a bit awkward and won't error if you pass bad args.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you're attempting to do can be accomplished by using the splat operator at the time of method invocation, like such:

```
hello(*my_array)
```

Here's a complete example:

```
def foo(a, *b)
  puts a.inspect
  puts b.inspect
end

foo(*[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
```

Prints the following:

```
[1, 2]
[[3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

**Edit: Other solution**

Now that you've pasted the source my opinion is that the method should be re-written to take a single parameter instead of using the splat operator in the parameters to pull out the `first` and `rest`. The reason is that if the length of the multidimensional array changes at runtime you'd be better off pulling out `first` and `rest` inside the method so you're not having to use the splat everywhere.

```
def interleave(args)
    a, *args = args
    max_length = args.map(&:size).max
    padding = [nil]*[max_length-a.size, 0].max
    (a+padding).zip(*args).flatten.compact
end

foo([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
```

Comment: i've copy-pasted the actual method for reference, to show that your last suggestion (re-writing the method to accept just one array) will not work in this case.  However, your original suggestion seems to work.

Comment: @allenwlee I edited my last suggestion to show better how it would work in your specific case

Comment: yes i like how you refactored the `interleave` method.  thanks.